# How does location of CSS stylesheets affect browser's progressive rendering?

Tags: html, css, performance, browser

I've read that putting CSS stylesheets outside of the document HEAD prohibits progressive rendering to avoid having to redraw elements of the page if their styles change, but why is this?  Does it just check to see if any CSS stylesheets are outside the HEAD and delay the rendering?  Why can't it just decide to load all the stylesheets first, regardless of the location within the HTML?

Answer (score 2):

Well, I guess that browsers do not wait until they get the entire file (and linked files (.js, .css...)) from the server, for then to render everything in the background and then display it to the user all at once. If you have Firefox, Press F12 and check the last tab... there you can see how the browser loads things.

Unlike downloading a large file, say 200 MiB, browsers usually start displaying whatever they get from the server, as soon as they get it, while still downloading the html/php/whatever file.

You may not notice much of a difference nowadays, with fast computers and fast Internet connections, but I'm pretty sure that, if you throttle your Internet connection, you can simulate this behaviour (page slowly loading).

Having this in mind, it kind of makes sense that the browser would have to "re-render" everything, if the stylesheets were at the end of the page, doesn't it?

Answer (score 2):

When a browser looks at HTML, it goes from top-to-bottom. It can't know whether there are stylesheets at the bottom before loading the HTML. The reason you load your stylesheets in the `<HEAD>` is so, as you said, it can progressively render the DOM objects with the styles you specified. When it sees the `<link rel=stylesheet>` it makes a request to get the CSS file. In terms of performance some pages would load really slowly if the browser had to scan through the whole html file for all the stylesheets, determine what styles needed to be applied, and THEN loaded the HTML. From designing-a-browser perspective, I think this only seemed logical.

In general, the idea is HTML provides content and CSS provides styling so they are to be kept separate. I guess browsers were designed so if they did not find a stylesheet, they'd just simply load the HTML anyways because in all honesty CSS isn't really "necessary". It's just eye candy which is an aesthetic that is important to us humans.

Having stylesheets at the top or in the `<HEAD>` gives the browser a "heads up" (haha!) knowledge of what styles you want to put so it looks nice and then once it reaches the bottom, it will see the stylesheet and then load it.

There is a really good blog post about [how browsers work](http://taligarsiel.com/Projects/howbrowserswork1.htm#The_order_of_processing_scripts_and_style_sheets) that might be useful.

Comment: second thought - what is the better way - to put css in `<head>` or `<link>`?

Comment: @EL not sure what you mean... `<link>` helps you reference a stylesheet which, as I said above should go in the `<head>`. If you are asking the difference between putting actual CSS in the `<head>` vs storing the CSS in a stylesheet, the difference is little to none but if you have a lot of styles, a stylesheet lets you organize it better.

Comment: Yeah I'm curious of what is more convinient for frowser - linked CSS (`<link>`) or 'embedded' (placed in `head` as text). But linking has at least one issue. I notice it sometimes. It's when document is loaded and displayed, but css's not

Comment: @EL using stylesheets I believe is actually faster. See [here](http://www.quora.com/Cascading-Style-Sheets/Is-there-a-speed-difference-between-inline-CSS-styles-and-those-applied-from-a-style-sheet). In a nutshell, by using stylesheets, the browser can cache the styles for the user so load times will be faster in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Well, adding a `<style>` tag outside of the `<head>` isn't actually legal in [HTML5](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/document-metadata.html#the-style-element).

Edited to add: unless you're using scoped styles, which only Firefox supports.

Comment: Yep. A lot of people either don't know that or forget about it.

Comment: i think it's not valid for any (x)html doctype not just 5. here's 4 [specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/present/styles.html#h-14.2.3) on styles. At the end it's browser dependent on how/when elements render. Look at IE and tables :( Scripts in the body will also slow down rendering, that's why it's best in the head or at the end of body

Comment: @Stephe, Please elaborate on "scoped styles".